# Merge Raphael Rect shapes

Tags: svg, raphael

Trying to get these 2 raphael elements to both change color when hovered over one or the other. Here is the code I have. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var loge_1 = rsr.set();
loge_1a = rsr.rect(235.457, 287.645, 32.523, 45.486),
loge_1b = rsr.rect(235.139, 277.626, 32.933, 6.701);
loge_1.push(loge_1a,loge_1b);
loge_1.attr(logeFill);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you got the code from ReadySetRaphael .... no doubt they have a very good algorithm for Raphael conversion ... try some large SVG files sometime and they will give you a good result .... anyways try this ...

```
loge_1.mouseover(function(){
    loge_1.attr({'fill':'your Desired Color'});
}
loge_1.mouseout(function(){
    loge_1.attr({'fill':'original color'});
}
```

this should change the color of both your rects .... Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response but not exactly what I was looking for. You are correct this did come from ReadySetRaphael, but what I am trying to achieve is having these 2 rectangles act as one element, so if I hover over just one rectangle both change color, then on mouse out both go back to normal.

I have been able to achieve this using paths which were very easy to combine but rectangles I am find to be a little more difficult. [Here is a link of my svg's to get an idea of what I am trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/ArKDp/37/)

Comment: here is a quick fix to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ArKDp/40/ .... the Raphael set cannot be referenced as 'this' the way you were doing ... have a look and let me know if this is what you were looking for .... as the event is bound to individual elements hence this does not reference the set but the element that triggers the event ....

Answer (score 0):

Well after searching I didn't find much on the subject. So I have read up on svg elements and changed my "rect" to "path". [Here is the W3C svg documentation](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html)

[And here is the jsfiddle with "path"](http://jsfiddle.net/knottAverage/ArKDp/38/)

To find my rectangles paths I just opened the svg file in Adobe AI. Then made sure my documents units was set to pixels. From there I opened my info window and just copied the my anchor points of my rectangles x & y coordinates into my "path" and presto I have 2 shapes acting as one.